# Cross join Sql Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](50) NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[State](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
             [CountryId] [int] NULL references Country(Id))

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
             [StateId] [int] NULL references State(Id))

Value in table
```

Country

```
-------
1 USA
2 UK
```

State

```
-----
1 NY 1
2 NSW NULL
```

City

```
-----
1 Sydney 2
2 Mumbai NULL
3 Delhi 1
```

Now I want the City.Name,State.Name,Country.Name list with NULL value too.

e.g Sydney NSW NULL
     Delhi NY USA
Avoid Duplicate Record

I try this Query  But some Mistake in it:

```
SELECT        Country.name, City.Name AS Expr1, State.Name AS Expr2
FROM            City CROSS JOIN
                         State CROSS JOIN
                         Country
WHERE        (City.StateId IN
                             (SELECT        StateId
                               FROM            City AS City_1)) OR
                         (State.CountryId IN
                             (SELECT        CountryId
                               FROM            State AS State_1))
```

Comment: @MartinSmith : it's not show me NULL value.

Comment: I don't know how much it's correct question they ask me in interview.

Comment: SELECT        Country.name, City.Name AS Expr1, State.Name AS Expr2
FROM            City CROSS JOIN
                         State CROSS JOIN
                         Country
WHERE        (City.StateId IN
                             (SELECT        StateId
                               FROM            City AS City_1)) OR
                         (State.CountryId IN
                             (SELECT        CountryId
                               FROM            State AS State_1))

Comment: please read this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: You should have a look at [Using joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472.aspx). What you need here could be done with a `left outer join`.

Comment: Cross joins are not in any way shape or form the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT        C2.name, C.Name AS Expr1, S.Name AS Expr2
FROM            City c 
LEFT OUTER  JOIN State s ON c.stateid = s.id
LEFT OUTER  JOIN Country c2 on s.countryId = c2.id
```

Comment: Hi Rs: It's not correctly working.I change my query please look in it