# Join columns of two CSV files using LINQ in C#.net

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, datatable

I'm doing a project that includes two csv files and convert them to dataTables and I want to join them and assign it to a new one. Only **BIN** or **BBL** columns are fixed, others might change. I am not that much accustomed with linq. The result might be something like:

```
    if radioButton1.checked{
    join all the columns in dt1; //dt1 = dt1 + dt2
    }
    else if radioButton2.checked{
    join all the columns in dt2; //dt2 = dt2 + dt1
    }
```

Now, if radioButton1 is enabled, then dt1 and dt2 has same column, like **BBL** and in dt1 there are 4 rows of **BBL** and in dt2 has 5 rows, where the first 4 matches exists in dt1 but the 5th one is new then it'll add this row in dt1 . For radioButton2, vise-versa.

I think the following kind of sql query might help:

```
SELECT * FROM dt1,dt2 GROUP BY BBL
```

I'm sure that it'll add the common ones in dt1 and dt2, but if dt2 has an extra row then will it work or not, that I don't know.

Comment: Show us your data columns and what exactly you want.

Comment: Provided the example in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789657/how-to-merge-datatable/10789751

Comment: @Dead Pool : Same query here ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538197/cross-join-sql-query

Comment: I don't need the sql query, I need the linq query; using System.Linq.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. If you can explain with pseudo code what you need done, you will get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

look this

```
var ret = from x in dt1.AsEnumerable()
    join y in dt2.AsEnumerable() on x.Field<int>("ID") equals y.Field<int>("ID") into z
    from y in z.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        ID = x.Field<int>("ID"),
        VAL = x.Field<string>("VAL")
     };
```